# How to alter subheading (not main heading) numbering in Microsoft Word?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010, text-formatting

I am currently trying to write a PhD thesis in Microsoft Word. For my main chapters, Heading 1 is numbered such that it reads "Chapter 1", "Chapter 2" etc. and so the Heading 2 subheadings have the chapter number and the section number e.g. "1.2", "1.3" etc. I have created a custom style based on Heading 1 style for appendix titles so they read "Appendix 1:" "Appendix 2:" etc. but I want the subheadings not to read just e.g. "1.2" but to read "A1.2" or "Appendix 1.2", so that they still follow the appendix heading number but are distinguishable from the numbering of the main chapter subsections. Is there any way of doing this without just removing the numbering from the appendices and entering it manually?

An alternative would be to use captions instead of subheadings and number them to "include chapter number" , however the only options I have in the "Chapter starts with style:" list are headings 1-9, my custom "Appendix Heading" is not present. Is there some way of making it show up in the list?